# How can mitochondria DNA overtake the nucleus?

Tags: science-based, biology

The Scarlet King is an eldritch god formed as the manifestation of the tension between the modern world and the pre-modern world and the rage it creates. Originally it existing as the concept of there being something greater than man, such as gods or the supernatural, or magic. As modernity approached and people began to understand their world through science and technology, the tension between both worlds raged and led to it's creation.

As magic has disappeared from the world, the Scarlett king must enter our plane through normal means. This god was being into the mortal world through one of the king's brides as completely human. However, his mitochondria DNA came from this demon. Mitochondria DNA is separate from the DNA of the nucleus, which comes from it's human parents and takes up most of the cell. It is donated by the mother, although has genes separate from her.

What I need is an explanation for the mitochondria to take control of its cells nucleus in the body on a full scale. This will slowly transform the individual into the demon it was meant to be at a certain point. Through what means can mitochondria be used to hijack the cell to make this happen?

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. Mitochondrial DNA is fully functional, it actually operates in any living eukaryiotic cell. And it is transmitted only on the maternal line. Being fully functional and operational, it can do whatever it is programmed to do, and *by necessity* it works in all cells of the body. You may want to explain what you mean by "takes over the cells"...

Comment: Do you want the resulting demon to be fertile, or this "take over" process can destroy the original DNA?

Comment: @Alexander does that matter?

Comment: @Incognito for a full takeover, more scientific explanation would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

DNA is basically a mold for a chemical substance. RNA and mRNA (I always forget when which one occurs) are then used to copy this formula and transport this to the part of the cell that can react to it. So some mRNA will go into the Mytochondria and cause the Mytochondria to start producing specific chemicals.

What you need is for the Mytochondria to migrate through the cell into the ribosomes surrounding the nucleus. Once it arrives in the nucleus (probably ripping a large part of the nuvleus and ribosomes apart) the mytochondria would need to recognize where it is, cause the complete destruction of the remaining DNA and then grow into a fully functioning nucleus itself.

A potential alternative is that the mytochondria moves around until it touches the ribosomes surrounding the nucleus and then destroys that while it starts throwing (m)RNA around to cause the cell to produce new ribosomes around it. Virusses also insert (m)RNA into its host cells and trick the cell into producing more virusses but I dont know how far they'll go into destroying the host's DNA.

The last option is during cell division. As the cell seperates its DNA and grows new nuclei etc the mytochondria destroy the existing DNA and substitute it with that of themselves.

Comment: DNA is transcribed into mRNA, but RNA [imported to the mitochondria](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28115039) are typically noncoding types.  These include tRNA (for shuttling amino acids during translation, when mRNA becomes protein), rRNA (ribosomal; the things that do the translation) and miRNA (lots of things, many of which aren't fully understood)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it still a valid hypothesis that the mitochondria were once separate cells that either penetrated the cells they now live in or that they were absorbed by them?

Based on that you may assume it is possible to do this the other way around. And as the previous answer suggests, I think the best way to do it would be during the cell's reproduction.

Comment: As far as I know current hypothesis is that mitochondria was intercellar parasite, wich then became simbiont.